# Non-equal spacing comparing between \left, \right and their \big equivalents

Tags: math-mode, plain-tex

The following two examples differ only with that in the first `\left` and `\right` are used, and in the second they are replaced with equivalent `\Biggl` and `\Biggr`. But spacing differs slightly. Why?

```
$$ \pi(n) = \sum_{m=2}^n \left \lfloor \biggl ( \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \bigl \lfloor (m/k) \big/ \lceil m/k \rceil \bigr \rfloor \biggr )^{-1} \right \rfloor $$

$$ \pi(n) = \sum_{m=2}^n \Biggl \lfloor \biggl ( \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \bigl \lfloor (m/k) \big/ \lceil m/k \rceil \bigr \rfloor \biggr )^{-1} \Biggr \rfloor $$
```

Comment: The example might be simpler: `$1\bigl(\big|\bigr)1$` versus `$1\left(\big|\right)1$`